# When to use requestScope in jstl?

Tags: jstl

A jstl variable is set in request scope in a jsp

```
<c:set var="name" value="Tiger" scope="request" />
```

This variable is accessed from a jspf included to this jsp. Now, is there any difference in accessing the variable in these two ways ?

```
1) <c:out value="${name}" />
2) <c:out value="${requestScope.name}" />
```

When to use requestScope ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You use requestScope when you absoluetely want your object to come from the request, and not from the page, session or application scope. Inded, using `${name}` will search for a `name` attribute in the page, then in the request, then in the session, then in the application.

Let's say that some other code in the JSP set a `name` attribute in the page scope. But you want to access the name in the request: you're forced to use requestScope.

Let's say the session might have a `name` attribute. Not using `requestScope.name` would return the session-scoped name if the JSP forgot to set the name attribute in the request scope.

If the goal of the JSP fragment is to access something set in the enclosing JSP, maybe this JSP fragment should be a JSP tag, and you should pass the name as an argument to this tag.

Answer (score 3):

Within my research (I am also new one for jstl),
request scope can set values to request page from response page  for example assume that we have a page called ***index.jsp***  and its action page is **index_action.jsp**

if we, set values to the action page

```
<c:set var="nme" scope="request" value="Janaka aravinda"/>
<%  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response); %>
```

(// I created `nme` variable and set its value as `Janaka aravinda`. and back to  reload request page(index.jsp) )

Now we can call `nme`  in ***index.jsp*** `nme` variable as  follow
 Request value

```
<c:out value="${nme}"/>
```